# Can you Augment the Aegis' Astral Suit mods that emulates Psionic Powers?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, psionics

- Example Aegis suit have Increased Size mod that emulates or out right let the user use the Expansion power.
- Can you Aegis use their PP pool to augment the Suit mod as written as the power. Meaning Aegis using Increased Size grows 1 size category larger. But when configuring the suit can the Aegis use the Augment cost to make the size increase double. If you could, then using Increased Size, Improved can have a size in crease of up to 4x norm right?
- Expansion:
  DESCRIPTION
  This power causes instant growth, doubling your height, length, and width and multiplying your weight by 8. This increase changes your size category to the next larger one. You gain a +2 size bonus to Strength, a –2 size penalty to Dexterity (to a minimum of 1), a –1 size penalty on attack rolls and AC due to your increased size.

If your new size is Large or larger, you have a space of at least 10 feet and a natural reach of at least 10 feet. This power does not change your speed.

If insufficient room is available for the desired growth, you attain the maximum possible size and can make a Strength check (using your increased Strength score) to burst any enclosures in the process. If you fail, you are constrained without harm by the materials enclosing you—you cannot crush yourself to death by increasing your size.

All your equipment, worn or carried, is similarly expanded by this power. Melee and projectile weapons deal more damage.

Other psionic or magical properties are not affected by this power. Any affected item that leaves your possession (including a projectile or thrown weapon) instantly returns to its normal size. This means that thrown weapons deal their normal damage (projectiles deal damage based on the size of the weapon that fired them). Multiple effects that increase size do not stack, which means (among other things) that you can’t use a second manifestation of this power to further expand yourself.

Augment You can augment this power in one or more of the following ways.

- If you spend 6 additional power points, this power increases your size by two size categories instead of one. You gain a +4 size bonus to Strength, a –4 size penalty to Dexterity (to a minimum effective Dexterity score of 1), a –2 size penalty on attack rolls, and a –2 size penalty to Armor Class due to your increased size.
- If you spend 6 additional power points, you can manifest this power as a swift action instead of a standard action.
- If you spend 2 additional power points, this power’s duration is 10 minutes per level rather than 1 minute per level.

Answer (score 3):

No. Aegis customizations are supernatural abilities, even when they mimic psionic powers or apply their effects. Power points are never spent on them unless they explicitly say so (and only two do), even when you want to. Moreover, when a customization says it applies the effect of a given power, you should assume it means the power without any augmentation.

Moreover, the increased size customization applies the effects of the *expansion* power to the suit and its wearer as a constant effect. You never manifest the power, so there is never an opportunity to augment it. Note that if you could, it would obviate the improved increased size customization.